# why does my rewrite rule without redirect give a 500 error?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i want to rewrite urls like

```
mysite.com/eng?sentence=cat
```

to show like:

```
mysite.com/eng/cat
```

I dont want a redirect just a rewrite. so I tried altering a rewrite rule i found, the example before i edited it had a R=301 in it originally:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /eng\?sentence=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^eng\?sentence=$ /english/%1? [R=302,NC,L]
```

but when i remove the R=301 from the 2nd line it gives a 500 error.

how can I write this kind of rewrite rule? Im not great with this regex stuff, nor am i familiar with this

my htaccess file:

```
# Use PHP5.3 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

Options -Indexes -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /eng\?sentence=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^eng\?sentence=$ /english/%1? [R=302,NC,L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use line end anchor `$` OR else just reply on `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/eng\?sentence=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /eng/%1? [NC,L,R=302]
```

Most likely 500 is because of looping due to other rules in your .htaccess. I suggest you posting full `.htaccess` code in your question.

Comment: your version also gave me 500 error, so i posted my htaccess contents in my edit.

Comment: Can you **comment out** both `ErrorDocument` lines and re-test?

Comment: Did you get a chance to test this by `commenting out both ErrorDocument lines`?

Comment: i removed the error document lines and still gives 500 error.

Comment: Actually you are making a mistake by removing `R=301` from above rule. Think about it, you need to redirect long URL to pretty URL and that required `R` flag.

Comment: i put the R back, but this rule still doesnt effect the urls

Comment: I think you've been asking quite a few different questions on same problem. This code is fully tested and working code. I suggest you to provide more details about your setup and cleanup your config issues.